# Filter Query in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have two `commentRootIdentityFields` in elastic search like given below

```
commentRootIdentityFields": [
{
"key": "endPointId",
"value": "dummy-endpoint"
},
{
"key": "api_id",
"value": "AU5ohQ6CQ50uGOgYbW0a"
},
{
"key": "projectId",
"value": "project-97cafcff-bc96-4b01-bd3b-fce66216674b"
}
]
```

and

```
commentRootIdentityFields": [
{
"key": "projectId",
"value": "project-97cafcff-bc96-4b01-bd3b-fce66216674b"
},
{
"key": "endPointId",
"value": "dummy-endpoint"
}
]
```

Now I want to a search query using only the project id and endpoint so that Elasticsearch returns only the second `commentRootIdentifier` field. Right now I am using BooleanQueryFilter must but it does not work.

Comment: `commentRootIdentityFields` should be `nested`.

Comment: Can a 'commentRootIdentityFields' have more than one endPoint/projectId" ?

Comment: No, it will have unique key value pair.